# not able to use g++ from Fedora

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, g++, glibc

```
$ yum list | grep gcc
arm-gp2x-linux-gcc.i686            4.1.2-11.fc12          @fedora               
arm-gp2x-linux-gcc-c++.i686        4.1.2-11.fc12          @fedora               
gcc.i686                           4.4.3-4.fc12           @updates              
libgcc.i686                        4.4.3-4.fc12           @updates              
avr-gcc.i686                       4.4.2-2.fc12           updates               
avr-gcc-c++.i686                   4.4.2-2.fc12           updates               
compat-gcc-34.i686                 3.4.6-18               fedora                
compat-gcc-34-c++.i686             3.4.6-18               fedora                
compat-gcc-34-g77.i686             3.4.6-18               fedora                
compat-libgcc-296.i686             2.96-143               fedora                
gcc-c++.i686                       4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
gcc-gfortran.i686                  4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
gcc-gnat.i686                      4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
gcc-java.i686                      4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
gcc-objc.i686                      4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
gcc-objc++.i686                    4.4.3-4.fc12           updates               
mingw32-gcc.i686                   4.4.1-3.fc12           fedora                
mingw32-gcc-c++.i686               4.4.1-3.fc12           fedora                
mingw32-gcc-gfortran.i686          4.4.1-3.fc12           fedora                
mingw32-gcc-objc.i686              4.4.1-3.fc12           fedora                
mingw32-gcc-objc++.i686            4.4.1-3.fc12           fedora                
msp430-gcc.i686                    3.2.3-3.20090210cvs.fc12
$
```

gcc works fine on .c files but fails on .cpp files saying:

> $ gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus':
>   execvp: No such file or directory

g++ fails saying:

> $ g++: Command not found.

**What should I do to be able to compile C++ files?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gcc-c++ is not installed.

The `yum list` command shows all packages, not just the installed packages.  The packages that are installed are prefixed with an ampersand or "@" sign.  The packages that are not installed (but are available to be installed) lack the ampersand.

To see what is installed try the command `rpm -qa`.  Or in your example `rpm -qa | grep gcc`

Oddly enough, if you didn't just grep for gcc, you would have been able to see the "Installed packages" and "Available packages" output lines between the two sets.

Answer (score 13):

you need to install the gcc-c++ package:

`yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: @Nitrodist: `yum list` doesn't list the installed packages, it lists all available packages. The package `gcc-c++` is presumably available through some sort of update repository.

Comment: @Nitrodist - If there had been an `@` prefixing the `updates` in that line, then that would mean that it was installed, without the `@` prefix, it just means that it is available for installation.